# Added a tableview in a viewcontroller. How do I load tableview cells

Tags: xcode, ios5.1

I have a view controller

- In `storyboard`, added `tableview` to view controller.
- Created an `IBOutlet` for `tableview` to View controller's header file.
- The view controller's header file includes an resultsarray
- Changed the @interface to include  delegates `UITableViewDelegate`, `UITableViewDataSource`
- View controller implementation file has mandatory `tableview` protocols

  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

The view controller has search button in `storyboard` and `IBAction` in view controller header file. On click of search button, results are obtained. How do I load the array and redisplay `tableview` with results in search method. After I loaded the results in array, I tried `[self viewdidload];`, hoping the cells will be loaded. But didn't. I thought of calling
`[self.detailView cellForRowAtIndexPath:?indexpath]`, but dontknow what the value of index path is. Appreciate help from guru's to load the `UItableviewcell`

Thanks

Comment: You linked your uitableview's delegate and datasource to your view controller in your storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `reloadData` or `reloadSections` methods of `tableView` in order to reload your tableView from data source.

```
// you fill your array with results here...
// and then call
[tableView reloadData];
```

This will call `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` methods for every cell to update its data.

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is the reference.

Comment: give me the syntax or statement. Let me check the reference too

Comment: @dreamrazor,You made my day. I was banging with splitviewcontroller earlier and went my way with a tableview in viewcontroller. Looking good

Comment: Glad it helped! I'm dreamzor not dreamrazor :D